# Fixed Position in a certain area CSS

Tags: css, position, fixed

I'm working with a side navigation bar and I'd like it to be a fixed position on the screen, but I want it to stop being fixed after you scroll so far down. Is there any way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function. On scroll this function will trigger. Write the if condition inside function to remove fixed

```
$( "#target" ).scroll(function() {
    if($(element).height() === "500px") {
        // remove scroll fixed
        $(scroll).css("position","relative") //or use absolute also.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it's already fixed, the only thing you have to do is the following:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() > 150){
    $('#nav').css('position', 'relative');
}
```

And of course, change `#nav` to your own selector and `150` to the value you desire.